# In Typescript, can SortMeta[] bet set to a descending order

Tags: angular, typescript

This should be pretty simple but I'm having trouble finding the answer.

Can the SortMeta interface be set so that it has a descending order?

For example, if I want to have a table that is sorted with the most recent entries at the top:

```
sorting: SortMeta[] = [{field: 'lastUpdatedDate', order: 1 }];
```

Can I update this so that it is in descending order?

Thanks much

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how to write code to take the array and sort it? Or are you trying to have the `SortMeta` type have a built-in guarantee that it can only store sorted data?

Comment: Just trying to write code to have it sort it.  As it is it sorts fine - it's just that I need it to sort with the greatest lastUpdatedDate at the top.

Comment: I guess you are talking about primeng? The interface definition is a bit stupid. The values possible are 1 and -1.